# Watir (Ruby) возвращает ошибку при попытке нажать на кнопку

Tags: ruby, test-automation

Изучаю Watir (версия 6.10). Пытаюсь запустить самый обычный тест - открыть Google, ввести поисковую фразу и кликнуть Поиск. Но каждый раз возникает ошибка в консоли на этапе нажатия кнопки - что-то вроде того, что данная кнопка некликабельна. По умолчанию используется chromedriver. Код:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('https://www.google.com.ua')
browser.input(name: 'q').send_keys('watir')
browser.element(:css => 'input[type=submit][name=btnK]').click
browser.title
browser.close
```

Пробовал делать поиск элемента через browser.input(:name = 'btnK'). Ошибка та же:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': unknown error: Element <input value="Поиск в Google" aria-label="Поиск в Google" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk"> is not clickable at point (453, 411). Other element would receive the click: <div class="sbqs_c">...</div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:81:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:81:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:164:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:579:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:326:in `click_element'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:72:in `click'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.2/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:134:in `block in click'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.2/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:658:in `element_call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.2/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:125:in `click'
    from 1.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Причина оказалась в поисковых подсказках Google. При введении поисковой фразы Google предлагает свои варианты, из-за чего кнопка "Поиск" сьезжает вниз, и скрипт почему то больше не может найти эту кнопку на страница. Если выбрать какой-то некликабельный текст на странице и, после введение поискового слова, кликнуть на него, то выпадающий список с подсказками пропадут, а кнопка поиска снова станет доступной.

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('https://www.google.com.ua')
browser.input(name: 'q').send_keys('watir')
browser.div(class: '_Cbu').click  #click text
browser.element(:css => 'input[type=submit][name=btnK]').click
puts browser.title 
browser.close
```

Не самое красивое решение. Если кто-то предложит более адекватный вариант - буду рад.

Comment: Попробуй `.send_keys("watir\n")` -- в конце ввода нажмется Ентер, и формы обычно его обрабатывают вместо нажатия кнопки. И используй по умолчанию в коде на Ruby двойные кавычки, а не одинарные -- не слушай неопытных хипстеров, коих на этом сайте вагон, вот увидишь сейчас.

Comment: Равно как не меняйте стиль кода лишь по той причине, что вам так сказал кто-то в интернетах. Выясните сами, чем двойные кавычки лучше (и/или хуже).